# storing rgb values in an array

Tags: arrays, processing, rgb

Im having trouble storing my rgb image values in a 2d array. How do i store a 3 values in one 2d array. And whats the best why to return those values since i get the error cant convert from float[][] to float[].

```
PImage img;

void setup()
{
  img = loadImage("leaf.jpg");
  size(img.width,img.height); 
}

void draw(){

  background(0);
  float[] m = storedPixels();
  println(m);
}  

float[] storedPixels(){ 

  int w = img.width;
  int h = img.height;
  float [][] c = new float[h][w];

  img.loadPixels();
  for(int y = 0; y < img.height; y++){
    for(int x = 0; x < img.width; x++){
      int loc = x + y * img.width;

      float r = red(img.pixels[loc]);       //Finds the amount of red is at a specific pixel.
      float g = green(img.pixels[loc]);
      float b = blue(img.pixels[loc]);

      c[y][x] = {r,g,b};
    }
  }
  img.updatePixels();

  return c;

}
```

Comment: v.k.'s answer is great. I'm just wondering, why are you storing the colours: 1.) as floats (you get them as int type by default) 2.) what is the advantage of using a 2d array ? (if this is just an exercise nevermind me and have fun :) )

Answer (score 1):

You can make a class to group the data together, or use Processing's color almost data type (although color will combine the components again), or even use PVector to store them together `new PVector (r,g,b)`, and retrieve using dot notation `pv.x = r | pv.y = g | pv.z = b`.
color in Processing is simple an int where components are stored like AAAARRRRGGGGBBBB.

here a sample using PVector

```java
PImage img;
PVector[][] m;
int i, j;

void setup()
{
  while (img==null) {
    img = loadImage("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b1/Indica_leaf.jpg");
  }
  size(img.width, img.height); 
  m = storedPixels();
}

void draw() {
  i =  (i + 1) % (width-1);
  j =  (j + 1) % (height-1);

  background(color(m[i][j].x, m[i][j].y, m[i][j].z));
}  

PVector[][] storedPixels() { 

  int w = img.width;
  int h = img.height;
  PVector [][] c = new PVector[w][h];

  img.loadPixels();
  for (int y = 0; y < img.height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < img.width; x++) {
      int loc = x + y * img.width;

      float r = red(img.pixels[loc]);       //Finds the amount of red is at a specific pixel.
      float g = green(img.pixels[loc]);
      float b = blue(img.pixels[loc]);

      c[x][y] = new PVector(r, g, b);
    }
  }

  return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rgb[][] = { r, g, b}, {r1, g2, b2}, ... }
```

I suggest visiting Docs for this or a tutorial on [Multidimensional Arrays](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c7/s5.html).